# Why is old constructor for function called?

Tags: javascript, prototype

It is my understanding that when you change the function prototype of a function to point to a different object the constructor of the new prototype will point to the new object's prototype constructor.

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new:

> When the code new Foo(...) is executed, the following things happen:
>
> 1) A new object is created, inheriting from Foo.prototype.
>
> 2) The constructor function Foo is called with the specified arguments,
>   and with this bound to the newly created object. new Foo is equivalent
>   to new Foo(), i.e. if no argument list is specified, Foo is called
>   without arguments.
>
> 3) The object returned by the constructor function becomes the result of
>   the whole new expression. If the constructor function doesn't
>   explicitly return an object, the object created in step 1 is used
>   instead. (Normally constructors don't return a value, but they can
>   choose to do so if they want to override the normal object creation
>   process.)

Furthermore, from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Inheritance:

> We need to do one more thing before we move on. After adding the last
>   line, Teacher.prototype's constructor property is now equal to
>   Person(), because we just set Teacher.prototype to reference an object
>   that inherits its properties from Person.prototype! Try saving your
>   code, loading the page in a browser, and entering
>   Teacher.prototype.constructor into the console to verify.

In my example below customPrototype inherits its properties from Object.prototype as far as I can tell and so once I reassign Person.prototype to that it should change the constructor as well. And logging it I see that the constructor does change!

```
// Some custom object to inherit  
var customPrototype = {
  name: "XYZ"
};

// Person has its prototype object pointing to Object.prototype
var Person = function() {  
  this.name = "Not XYZ";
};

// Prints function() {this.name = "Not XYZ";}
console.log(Person.prototype.constructor);

// Change Person prototype to point to the custom prototype object
Person.prototype = customPrototype;

// Prints function Object() { [native code] }
console.log(Person.prototype.constructor);

var p = new Person();

// Prints Not XYZ
console.log(p.name);
```

Given the example above I expected the last name to print XYZ because nothing would be overwritten from the customPrototype object.

What am I missing? Why does it still call the Person function when (I think) it should be calling the Object.prototype.constructor?

Comment: If the object being instantiated has a property with the same name, it stops the lookup.  In this case, you are setting `this.name` in the constructor, which is "Not XYZ".  If after you create a new person object and `delete p.name`, the lookup will continue to the prototype .  Why keep looking for your wallet if you've already found it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Prototype.constructor` have nothing to do with object initialization. When you want to create an object, you call `new Person()`, which actually calls the `Person` function, passes the object as the context (`this`) into the function and returns that object. `Person` function is called, no matter what prototype you have for it. And because in this function you have a property `name` set to `Not XYZ`, it will have that value. It shadows the prototype property with the same name. If you will delete this property from the object and try to again access `name`, you will get the prototypes one.

```js
var customPrototype = {
  name: "XYZ"
};

var Person = function() {  
  this.name = "Not XYZ";
};

Person.prototype = customPrototype;
var p = new Person();
console.log(p.name);
delete p.name;
console.log(p.name);
```

We set the `prototype.constructor` to keep the precise construction of the object and if we want to have some checkings based on which type of the object is.

Implementing copy logic for the objects of the type `Person`.

```js
function Person(name) {  
   this.name = name;
};

Person.prototype.copy = function() {
  return new this.constructor(this.name); // Access by `constructor` property, it is not necessary to call directly `Person`
}

const person = new Person('Bob');
console.log(person.name);
const secondPerson = person.copy();
console.log(secondPerson.name);
console.log(person === secondPerson);
```

Comment: I knew that commenting out or deleting the line this.name = "Not XYZ" would result in the customPrototype name. So basically then the prototype.constructor is for testing if an object IS A instance of some constructor function right? Are there any other uses for prototype.constructor?

Comment: One reason is that. One of the reasons also is when we want to implement a copy method in that function